# Hibernate query.setString don't work

Tags: java, varchar2, setstring

Now I using hql in query.
The code is:

```
return session.createQuery(
                "from Company com "
                        + " where com.comId = "
                        + ":comId and com.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber")
                .setString("comId", comId).setString("phoneNumber",
                        phoneNumber).list();
```

the phoneNumber in DB is varchar2(255 char), and I using Oracle DB.

But this code can't work in java codes.
If the phoneNumber is "999-000-0001", it can work. I can get a record.
But if the phoneNumber is "USPersonal", I will not get the record.

In Company.java, the phoneNumber is String, and has get and set methods.

In DB, I using Sql Developer, I can get all of the above.

I don't know, why it is? Is the setString doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem.

Because in this case, the phoneNumber come from file. In file, I ignored there has some space in phoneNumber " USPersonal   ", while in DB, it is "USPersonal" only.

So I didn't get this record.

The codes above are correct.
How careless of me!